# How can a Java byte variable be 128?

Tags: java, android

I probably miss some fundamental understanding of byte in Java. The following is a simplified excerpt from an app to illustrate the problem:

```
public class Foo
{
 byte b1;
 byte b2;
 byte bProblem;
}
```

foo is an instance of Foo.  The following has puzzled me for hours:

```
Log.d("Debug", "Before: " + String.valueOf(foo.bProblem));
if (foo.bProblem != (byte) 0x80) {
    foo.bProblem = (byte) 0x80;
    Log.d("Debug", "After: " + String.valueOf(foo.bProblem));
}
```

LogCat shows the following:

```
03-17 21:58:46.590: D/Debug(2130): Before: 128    
03-17 21:58:46.590: D/Debug(2130): After: -128
```

Eclipse's debugger always shows -128 (0x80) for foo.bProblem. This means the debugger cannot see what String.valueOf() reveals. How can a Java byte be 128?

I noticed this when adding foo.bProblem to a List caused:
Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=256; index=256

Could anyone offer some hint for me to understand this?

Edited:

I found later this happens only on an Intel Android emulator as I wrote in my comment following Joop's answer.

Comment: `byte` cannot hold `128`! The value of a `byte` should be in between `-128` and `127`.

Comment: That is my understanding. How can String.valueOf(foo.bProblem) produce 128?

Comment: The only way I can think of to produce `128` is to add a minus sign in front of `foo.bProblem` as `String.value(- foo.bProblem)`, where `foo.bProblem == (byte) 0x80`.

Comment: What is the Java version you are using?

Comment: The compiler compliance level is 1.6.

Comment: Yeah, please also give a complete code sample. I want to see how the byte member gets set.

Comment: Regarding the exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632480/597657

Comment: @–user1050755, sorry but I missed your question earlier. The value is assigned as following: foo.bProblem = ab[3];  ab is a byte array.

Answer (score 4):

A Java "byte  data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)." So when you assign a byte to +128 it essentially wraps back around to the lowest value of -128

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for details.

Answer (score 4):

String.valueOf does not take a byte, it takes one of the following:

boolean
char
char[]
double
float
int
long
Object

In your implementation you are actually calling String.valueOf(int value)
It does not actually contain the value of 128. Try printing

```
Log.d("Debug", "" + bProblem)
```

That should work.

EDIT--

What I'm trying to say is that String.valueOf is not actually looking at the value of the byte. It's looking at the same bits that make up the byte as an int and printing that.

Comment: I changed the code to Log.d("Debug", "Before: " + foo.bProblem), and got the same outcome.

Answer (score 4):

In the java virtual machine, the byte field bProblem will use an int. Now, `String.valueOf(int)` is used, as there is no byte variant. So (erroneously?) the field is taken as int, so unsigned, 128.

---

***Sorry, I tried to achieve a 128 but did not succeed (Java 7, Linux)***

I already became paranoid, you using a child class with an int field bProblem. Or more likely a compiled class being used with a java source not up-to-date compiled. Maybe you could try another compiler than that of eclipse.

Comment: But `byte b = (byte) 0x80; System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));` prints `-128`?

Comment: What value of a byte variable would result in String.valueOf(foo.bProblem) = "128"?  String.valueOf() is used just to show the problem.  My real issue is that foo.bProblem cannot be added to a List<Byte>.

Comment: Exactly. When assigning anything like 128 to a byte, the conversion to -128 is implict. It would otherwise make the whole language inconsistent. And to be honest, I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: foo.bProblem is assigned somewhere else, and I examined the assignment the same way showing it is assigned -128 (0x80). Suppose this variable is messed up somewhere that I do not know.  The question is: how can a byte variable by assigned a value beyond its scope? Again, Eclipse shows it is always -128 (0x80).

Comment: Recompile everything? Now you have got me worried too.

Comment: Thank you all for all the tips.  I really appreciate. I have finally found a possible cause.  I was using the Intel Android emulator that is about literally 10 times faster than other emulators, even faster than real devices, so it is my preferred means of testing Android apps.  I have just tried the app on an Android tablet, and it does not have this problem. Could the Intel Android emulator the culprit?